# Converting date format with PHP

Tags: php, joomla

I have a situation where I need to change the date format using PHP.

The site uses Joomla & k2. The template uses the following to obtain the articles publish date:

```
$itemCreated = JHTML::_('date', $item->created, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC4'));
echo $itemCreated;
```

This will output the date in the following date format: `A d B Y`

I need to change it to appear in the date format: `Y m d`

(note: For those familar with Joomla & K2: I DO NOT want to use a language override. This particular task needs to be done only using PHP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do in `PHP`

Assuming you are rcieving the `time` in `UNIX Timestamp`

```
$time = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($your_unix_timestamp));
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how I would combine that with the existing code that I need to convert (in my original post)

Comment: `$item->created` is this what gives you the time string?+

Comment: Then store the `$item->created` in a variable and use that variable in place of `$your_unix_timestamp` in the above snippet

Answer (score 0):

I had once the same issue with date formats in Joomla. This is a small code snippet I use sometimes:

```
        $theDate = new DateTime($item->created);
        $itemCreated= strftime("%Y %m %d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $theDate->format('n'), $theDate->format('j'), $theDate->format('Y')));
```

And a more complete implementation part of a class for a Joomla module development I did. You can also use these 2 functions passing $item->created as a parameter to formatDate() function.

```
   function buildDateObj($date) {
    try {
        $dateObj = new DateTime($date);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //  return $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
    return $dateObj;
}

function formatDate($date) {
    $formattedDate = '';
    if ($date !== "") {
        $currDate = buildDateObj($date);
        if ($currDate !== false) {
            $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
              $LangTag = $lang->getTag(); 
              setlocale(LC_TIME,  $LangTag);

            $formattedDate = strftime("%Y %m %d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $currDate->format('n'), $currDate->format('j'), $currDate->format('Y')));
            setlocale(LC_TIME, 0);
        }
    }
    return $formattedDate;
}

$itemCreated = formatDate($item->created)
```

The different [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) date formats.

Answer (score 0):

This is Joomla.

The code

```
JHTML::_('date', $item->created, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC4'));
```

actually fetches the **item created date** to the format: **DATE_FORMAT_LC4**.

The following formats are the defaults

```
DATE_FORMAT_LC="l, d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC1="l, d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC2="l, d F Y H:i"
DATE_FORMAT_LC3="d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC4="Y-m-d"
DATE_FORMAT_JS1="y-m-d"
```

each installed language in joomla changes those to their local format so in a multilingual website the users see their local format.

If you want to view a "FIXED" format no matter what the user local is, you could change:
this:

```
JHTML::_('date', $item->created, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC4'));
```

to this:

```
JHTML::_('date', $item->created, 'Y m d');
```